# Getting fatal error when including <stdlib>

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I got a fatal error that the file or directory `<stdlib>` is not found on `ubuntu 11.xx` when I typed `#include <stdlib>`.

Is `<stdlib>` deprecated/removed, or is there something wrong with my GCC installation?

Comment: fatal error!!! you need to include <stdlib.h> or <cstdlib>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In C++ code, include 'cstdlib' instead.

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

If you are using C, include 'stdlib.h'

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

In c++ code, always prefer the cXXX include instead of XXX.h

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are attempting to include the C standard library header `stdlib.h`.

Thing is, in C++, the old C headers `x.h` are *deprecated*; you should not use them. Fortunately, C++ allows you to use C++ versions of them:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

It's pretty much the same thing, but wrapped into the `std::` namespace ... and not deprecated.

Anyway, you got your error because there's certainly no standard header named just `stdlib`.